# Rails I18n: How to add a error translation key which is common for all model base errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

In my current application we use I18n. I have to add a :base error key which should be common for all models.
For ex: I would add `:common_error` in one place in `en.yml` file and use as follows,

```
@user.errors.add(:base, :common_error)
@post.errors.add(:base, :common_error)
..and so on
```

I'm really worried that if I should add `:common_error` key in all the models as there are more model present in the application.

My current `en.yml` file looks as follows,

```
en-uk:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      <<: *errors
        models:
          user:
            attributes:
              base:
                some_key: ""
          post:
            attributes:
              base:
                some_key: ""
```

I'm not sure if there is a simple solution that I haven't found. But any ideas would be appriciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply don't use a relative translation key -

```
@user.errors.add(:base, t(:common_error) )
```

If you pass a symbol to errors.add the translation uses the scope of the model.

Comment: Though my job is done.. I wonder if there is any solution using relative translation keys the way I explained in my question :)

Comment: You might be able to use node archors in the yaml file.  Then you would have a reference on every model's user:/attributes:/base: entry instead of explicit string.

Comment: I am trying to understand node anchors [here](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2785586). Do you have any simple example you could provide?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding errors through specific `models`, you can define additional error messages in the same way Rails handles its internal errors by using the `messages` key .

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      common_error: 'is common'
```

This will apply to both Active Record and Active Model models. If you only want it to apply to one or the other you could instead nest the `errors` under `activerecord` or `activemodel` like this:

```
en:
  activemodel:
    errors:
      messages:
        common_error: 'is common'
```